# Desktop icons rearrange voluntarily when adding/removing from Desktop Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gnome-shell, desktop-icons

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and found that icons move around when action is taken that causes a change to the Desktop. If, e.g., I unzip a file, the unzipped data replaces the location of the .zip, while the original file is moved to another location. On the other hand, moving icon (file) to the Trash, or restoring from Trash, causes unpleasant single blink of the whole desktop. Sometimes more than one icon changes position.

I wonder how to disable this feature.
It is default GUI (Gnome).